# Understanding the real estate part in the morning session

Tags: stocks, shareholder-meeting

I'm reading the [11. Munger: Commercial real estate downturn will be 'quite significant and quite unpleasant](https://buffett.cnbc.com/video/2023/05/08/morning-session---2023-meeting.html) part in the morning session

And I couldn't understand the following:

1. "It's whatever they can borrow without signing their name." -- Does it mean people borrow money without a contract or collateral?
2. "people that have become big in the real estate business" -- By "big", does it mean people get a lot of debt or make a lot of money?
3. "find out it doesn't work at current rates, and they hand it back to somebody that gave them all the money they needed to build it" -- Does it mean people borrows money at a low rate and lend it to someone else to buy a house?

Answer (score 2):

1. This refers to non-recourse loans. It's still secured (the property is collateral), but if you default on the loan the only thing the bank/lender can do is repossess the collateral (i.e. there's no recourse outside of the secured asset). Note that in most states, residential mortgages are considered recourse loans, meaning the lender can try to get a court judgment to put a lien on other assets if the foreclosed property doesn't pay off the loan.
2. Real estate often relies on leverage (borrowing), so big players in real estate almost universally use leverage. Without leverage, cash on hand is all there is to invest. That doesn't always mean making money. Buffett mentions that "the lenders are the ones that get the property" - this is because a company/person with a mortgage on a property might choose to default if they don't feel it's worth it to keep paying the mortgage (or be forced to default if they can't continue to pay). Two examples right now in San Francisco are the [Hilton](https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/companies/san-francisco-hilton-investor-will-stop-making-loan-payments/ar-AA1ccdV1) and [Westfield Mall](https://www.msn.com/en-us/money/companies/westfield-to-give-up-san-francisco-mall-as-fewer-shoppers-hit-occupancy-levels/ar-AA1cv5zu), both in the Union Square area, who are defaulting on their loans and giving the property back to the lenders.
3. The context here implies either construction loans or some type of variable loan. Essentially that the borrower was able to make things work when the rate was 2.5%, but current higher rates make payments untenable. For example, if a construction loan was maturing and a new loan is needed to replace it, or if the fixed period for a loan was ending.